# How can I get the weather in current location from Latitude and Longitude?

Tags: android

I want current location's **weather** from my `latitude` , `longitude.`

Comment: You should also look at this question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507441/best-weather-apis

Answer (score 0):

You can also give [this webservice](http://www.webservicex.net/ws/WSDetails.aspx?CATID=12&WSID=56) a try!

Comment: * what i have * my current application is returning me my location name and its latitude and longitude i want to get weather from my location name . can u give me sample of code .?